# Decryption of ElGamal ciphertext

Tags: elgamal-encryption

If someone says that the decryption of an ElGamal ciphertext is "x", how can I be sure that the real value is "x" and not "y", even if he is the owner of the respective private key?

Comment: Precise the context: Static/interactive? Bilinear group or not?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using El Gamal encryption in a group where the [decisional Diffie-Hellman problem is hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption#Security), you cannot. El Gamal is known to be [IND-CPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) in such groups.

If DDH is tractable and they assert that the cryptogram $(n,c)$ is of the form $(g^r,xa^r)$ then you can check $\mathrm{DDH}(g,a,n,c/x)$.

You can ask for additional information to prove their assertion, but this exceeds the parameters of your question.

Comment: This is about commitment or zero-knowledge.